# dojo EdgeToEdgeList: programmatically set the store

Tags: javascript, dojo

Here a very simple `dojo` snippet that doesn't work:

```js
require([
  "dojo/parser",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dijit/registry",
  "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList",
  "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList",
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(parser, on, dom, registry, EdgeToEdgeStoreList, Memory) {
  parser.parse();

  var records = [{
    deviceID: "1",
    state: "done"
  }, {
    deviceID: "2",
    state: "idle"
  }];

  var store = new Memory({
    data: records,
    idProperty: "deviceID"
  });

  registry.byId("list").setStore(store);  
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: false, async: true"></script>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollableView">
  <ul id="list" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList" data-dojo-props="itemMap: {deviceID: 'label'}, select: ''"></ul>
</div>
```

the `list` item is not found.
Is correct the way to fill the store and to set it for list?
Where is(are) my error(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why this doesn't work is that `parser.parse()` is also asynchronous, so you should wait for it to finish.

There is a difference between `dojo/domReady!` and `dojo/ready`, and in your situation you should actually use `dojo/ready`, since you have `parseOnLoad` config set to `false` (see more [here](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/04/17/dojodomready-vs-dojoready/)).

Now, since `dojo/ready` automatically waits for all parse calls to finish before the code is executed, you should have something like this:

```
parser.parse();
ready(function() {
  // put your logic in here
});
```

Another options is to just register a callback:

```
parser.parse().then(function() {
   // put your logic here
});
```

The easiest way to go about it though is to just set the `parseOnLoad` option to `true`, and then you can remove `parser.parse()` from your code and everything else can stay the same.

As a note, just one small error I noticed in your original snippet is that you are missing `EdgeToEdgeList` from the arguments to your module function.